# Best way to add "filter" options to MVC action, for new Web API feature of ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

The new Web API "stuff" looks great. I will be re-writing the foundation of my site into an API, but have a couple scenarios that I've got concern with.

Is it a bad idea to have an action that looks something like:

`GetProducts(long memberId, string categories, int minPrice, int maxPrice, ...)`

Where each variable is something the product can be filtered by. If the variable is null/empty it wouldn't use them to build the query.

Or is there another technique for reaching the same goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a view model:

```
public class FilterViewModel
{
    public long MemberId { get; set; }
    public string Categories { get; set; }
    public int MinPrice { get; set; }
    public int MaxPrice { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and then:

```
public IEnumerable<ProductViewModel> GetProducts(FilterViewModel filter)
{
    ...    
}
```

Comment: I would make the primitive properties of the View Model nullable like `code` public int? MinPrice { get; set; } `code`, so that it is easier with optional values.