# URL for MVC action with object parameters (using web API)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9553719/579299) the Answer suggests using an object as the parameter. What URL would I use to access that?
In the OP's first example, my original approach was to overload the action (not sure if overload is the right word) so I had:

```
public IEnumerable<NTOrder> Get()...

public IEnumerable<NTOrder> Get(int p)...

public IEnumerable<NTOrder> Get(int p, int q)
```

not elegant, I know, but if I change it to one object I don't know how to format the URL...

Old Code

```
public IEnumerable<NTOrder> Get() {
    //build NTOrderList
    return NTOrderList;
}
```

New Code

```
public class FilterView
{
    public int? fID { get; set; }
    public int? fCustomer { get; set; }
    public string fSalesPerson{ get; set; }
}

public IEnumerable<NTOrder> Get(FilterView queryFilter) {
    //build NTOrderList
    List<NTOrder> result = (from order in NTOrderList
                               where (order.OrderID == queryFilter.fID || queryFilter.fID == null)
                                  && (order.CustomerID == queryFilter.fCustomer || queryFilter.fCustomer == null)
                                  && (queryFilter.fSalesPerson == null || order.Salesperson.Equals(queryFilter.fSalesPerson))
                                select order).ToList();

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this answer](http://forums.asp.net/t/1807316.aspx/1) as a possible solution, which basically suggests passing the data as JSON in the url and adding a filter to convert that to a complex object, but as the OP in that post suggests it's not the most elegant way...anybody have a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

The URL would work in exactly the same way, with one querystring parameter for each property in the object.

Comment: I tried that...I get an exception message:
No MediaTypeFormatter is available to read an object of type 'FilterView' from content with media type ''undefined''.

Comment: I've posted my old & new code snippets...the old url was just http://localhost:3495/api/NTOrder. For the new code I've tried various things such as http://localhost:3495/api/NTOrder?fID=101 and other combinations with all/no variables